# Can't connect to Wi-Fi with 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi-driver

I have a 0bda:f179 RTL8189FTV chip for Wi-Fi. 
It does not work with Ubuntu.

`lsusb` shows `Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.` 
I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

My LAN is working fine, and with that I tried the below:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone git://github.com/ulli-kroll/rtl8188fu
cd rtl8188fu
make
sudo make installfw
sudo modprobe cfg80211
sudo insmod rtl8188fu.ko
sudo make install
```

These steps worked for the first time but now I'm not able to connect Wi-Fi. 
Please help if I'm missing anything.

and the problem existed even after reboot. 
So need a solution to solve this and make the problem go away forever.

Comment: Did you run a kernel update?

Comment: no.. @AulisRonkainen can you elaborate?

Comment: When you compile and install your own drivers if the kernel is updated, you'll have to install your drivers again. What does "these steps worked for the first time" mean? Did you check `dmesg` for errors?

Comment: the commands i used are mentioned above, after the first try itself the issue was resolved. but, when i restart the computer the issue comes back meaning the wifi adaptor is not functioning and i have to do all the steps again. @AulisRonkainen

Comment: Could you please try to add `cfg80211` to your `/etc/modules` file? That might work.